# Unable to parse as integer in Android

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes, number-formatting

I want to implement `encrypt` and `decrypt` operation for some `String` values. I have encrypted properly but I don't understand how to `decrypt` this value like:

`jsonString Values ={"Response":"NJGOkF2EvOIpfKG14LHQZrVfj\/OEJvopi+OKU+q5G2ynDbVUnIckfMLGCCsxcY9+BmVg+KJXF1ls\nGf2rWg73iyowyq6THyDfBS8uZnSp9PfS3bJCFb6YWX4\/\/uxjDwtZ","statusFlag":"true"}`

When I decrypt, I am getting `NumberFormatException`.

Here is my simple Crypto class

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;


    public class SimpleCrypto {

            public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext) throws Exception {
                    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
                    byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
                    return toHex(result);
            }

            public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted) throws Exception {
                    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
                    byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
                    byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
                    return new String(result);
            }

            private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
                    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
                    SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
                    sr.setSeed(seed);
                kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
                SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
                byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
                return raw;
            }


            private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
                SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
                    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
                byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
                    return encrypted;
            }

            private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
                SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
                    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
                byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
                    return decrypted;
            }

            public static String toHex(String txt) {
                    return toHex(txt.getBytes());
            }
            public static String fromHex(String hex) {
                    return new String(toByte(hex));
            }

            public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
                    int len = hexString.length()/2;
                    byte[] result = new byte[len];
                    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                            result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16).byteValue(); //2 * i, 2 * i + 2
                    return result;
            }

            public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
                    if (buf == null)
                            return "";
                    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2*buf.length);
                    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
                            appendHex(result, buf[i]);
                    }
                    return result.toString();
            }
            private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";
            private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
                    sb.append(HEX.charAt((b>>4)&0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b&0x0f));
            }

    }
```

This is log cat infomation .

```
01-03 11:30:51.154: W/System.err(437): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '{"' as integer
01-03 11:30:51.164: W/System.err(437):  at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:383)
01-03 11:30:51.164: W/System.err(437):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:372)
01-03 11:30:51.164: W/System.err(437):  at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:528)
01-03 11:30:51.164: W/System.err(437):  at com.json_to_server.SimpleCrypto.toByte(SimpleCrypto.java:63)
01-03 11:30:51.164: W/System.err(437):  at com.json_to_server.SimpleCrypto.decrypt(SimpleCrypto.java:20)
01-03 11:30:51.164: W/System.err(437):  at com.json_to_server.EncryptDecrypt_Demo.POST(EncryptDecrypt_Demo.java:202)
01-03 11:30:51.174: W/System.err(437):  at com.json_to_server.EncryptDecrypt_Demo$HttpAsyncTask.doInBackground(EncryptDecrypt_Demo.java:267)
01-03 11:30:51.174: W/System.err(437):  at com.json_to_server.EncryptDecrypt_Demo$HttpAsyncTask.doInBackground(EncryptDecrypt_Demo.java:1)
01-03 11:30:51.174: W/System.err(437):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
01-03 11:30:51.174: W/System.err(437):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
01-03 11:30:51.174: W/System.err(437):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
01-03 11:30:51.174: W/System.err(437):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
01-03 11:30:51.174: W/System.err(437):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
01-03 11:30:51.174: W/System.err(437):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

And i want to decrypt this value. I don't know where i have to change the code in my `SimpleCrypto class`

```
jsonString Values = {"Response":"NJGOkF2EvOIpfKG14LHQZrVfj\/OEJvopi+OKU+q5G2ynDbVUnIckfMLGCCsxcY9+BmVg+KJXF1ls\nGf2rWg73iyowyq6THyDfBS8uZnSp9PfS3bJCFb6YWX4\/\/uxjDwtZ","statusFlag":"true"}
```

Comment: Your logcat says 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '{"' as integer'. what does it mean?

Comment: I have verified and your input is valid and so is your logic, details below!

Comment: Use the "response" part of the JSON data only.Not the whole Json string as a String

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are `decrypting` the whole `JSON` string and I think you only need to `decrypt`

**this string :** 
`NJGOkF2EvOIpfKG14LHQZrVfj\/OEJvopi+OKU+q5G2ynDbVUnIckfMLGCCsxcY9+BmVg+KJXF1ls\nGf2rWg73iyowyq6THyDfBS8uZnSp9PfS3bJCFb6YWX4\/\/uxjDwtZ`

So you should `parse` the `JSON` and get `Response string` from `JSON` and then `decrypt` it.

> 

**UPDATE :
You can parse you json string like this :**

```
String value = "YOUR_JSON_STRING";
    try {
        JSONObject mJsonObject = new JSONObject(value);
        String response = mJsonObject.getString("Response");
        //Decrypt response string 

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now you have your `encrypted` `string` in `response variable`. Now you can `decrypt` `response string`.

Comment: Above is the response string from JSON which i got from server and this string i want to decrypt it.

Comment: Can you suggest me how to do ?

Comment: Whatever You told is already done by me then also it gives NumberFormatException at the line of "NJ" unable parse as a integer.

Comment: tazeenmulani: You're getting a NumberFormatException because the method toByte() expects the input string to be in hexadecimal, but the string in your example is not. I suspect that the JSON data is base64 encoded after it has been encrypted. This was probably done to prevent nulls or other characters from fudging up the HTTP stream. Try base64 decoding the string before running it through decrypt.

Comment: @JeffreyPortouw I had added my answer below on the same lines, decoded the BASE64 and tried the decryption to bytes too. Seems OP lost interest with it after all

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your class and it's working as i see. Here is my test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   String message = "Some string that i want to encrypt and decrypt";
   String key = "123";

   String encrypted = SimpleCrypto.encrypt(key, message);
   p(encrypted);

   String decrypted = SimpleCrypto.decrypt(key, encrypted);
   p(decrypted);
}

private static void p(String message) {
   System.out.println(message);
}
```

and output:

```
B7498FF642FA8B81289AE8E59E19F081A27B766BE3290617CC15F857BF055DA2668BF81181E26AE2F790968DF39CC070
Some string that i want to encrypt and decrypt
```

You're getting NumberFormatException because your class decrypts only hexed strings, but this one is not hexed.

Comment: I'm using your code line I'm getting BadPaddingException pad block currupted.

Comment: and also unable to parse "NJ" as integer.

Comment: i've told before about parse as integer - your class only decrypts strings in hex format. NJGOkF2EvOIpfKG14LHQZrVfj\... is not hex!

Answer (score 1):

You trying parse to Integer string 'NJ' as HEX-digits. But HEX is only 0-9 and A-F symbols. Change your income string to only HEX symbols.

Answer (score 1):

I think `result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16).byteValue();`  gives you error because your hexstring  may contain character literal so Integer.valueOf() function gives you `NumberFormatException`

for hexstring to byte array conversion please check [link]  https://stackoverflow.com/a/140861/3131537

hope that solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse the whole string which containts not only numbers but also text (String). Please review your code and then make this a question

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works, the interpretation of the data you are getting is misaligned with what is actually happening.

Your JSON response is not an encrypted byte array but an **encoded String**. To stream across an array of Bytes (or bits or any binary data for that matter) through a network, it is not generally sent in its raw format. Rather, you want to **encode** your raw data into **characters**.

Since your JSON response looks like a stream of characters and not a raw format of bytes, the first assumption I can make is it's an encoded data using one of the most common binary to String encoding - **Base64**.

The below string (response) is a **valid Base64** encoded String, while your decrypt method is expecting the ***Hex*** encoded stream of characters.

> NJGOkF2EvOIpfKG14LHQZrVfj/OEJvopi+OKU+q5G2ynDbVUnIckfMLGCCsxcY9+BmVg+KJXF1ls\nGf2rWg73iyowyq6THyDfBS8uZnSp9PfS3bJCFb6YWX4//uxjDwtZ

### Extracting the correct response:

Since JSON 'allows' you to escape front slashes and other escape sequences, your Base64 response needs to be slightly formatted.

I remove the escapes for front slashes and 'escape' the '\' for the line feed (\n). The resulting String looks like (notice \n):

```
NJGOkF2EvOIpfKG14LHQZrVfj/OEJvopi+OKU+q5G2ynDbVUnIckfMLGCCsxcY9+BmVg+KJXF1ls\\nGf2rWg73iyowyq6THyDfBS8uZnSp9PfS3bJCFb6YWX4//uxjDwtZ
```

This is a valid Base64 String, you can test it [here](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/) (replace \n with a line feed by pressing enter and bringing the rest of the text to the new line).

[image]

*Notice it downloads a binary file as a result - which proves the the decoded value is in fact a valid binary raw data.*

### Fixing the code:

As it's evident from `NumberFormatException`, your `decrypt` method is expecting a Hex encoded stream of characters which it does not get.

As per your code, the encrypt function would return the Hex encoded value of the String. This is valid as well since Hex is also a representation of binary values in a readable form. However, you might need to level set within your integration to be consistent with the encoding scheme.

Coming back to your algorithm, your decrypt methods expect the encrypted data in **Hex** form but what you get is a **Base64** encoded String.

Aligned to what your logic expects (I didn't want to make changes to your original base code)

1. We would have to **decode the Base64** encoded String - various flavors are available, I used `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` for this test.
2. **Convert it to Hex**
3. Feed it to the **decrypt** method

The sequences of steps translated like this in the code (within my test class main method):

```
String encoded = "NJGOkF2EvOIpfKG14LHQZrVfj/OEJvopi+OKU+q5G2ynDbVUnIckfMLGCCsxcY9+BmVg+KJXF1ls\\nGf2rWg73iyowyq6THyDfBS8uZnSp9PfS3bJCFb6YWX4//uxjDwtZ";

String key = "abc";

String decoded = toHex(Base64.decodeBase64(encoded));
System.out.println(decoded);

String decrypted = decrypt(key, decoded);
System.out.println(decrypted);
```

### Point about your encryption scheme:

Your AES encryption scheme uses a default AES scheme (`Cipher.getInstance("AES");`) which translates to `Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");` in SunJCE implementation.

When I run this with a random key `abc`

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
```

This of course is the ***scenario of a wrong key*** as I do not have the key which you would use to encrypt/decrypt your data.

You can test this scenario with the right key and the changes mentioned above, **it should work with your current encryption scheme.**

### My Test case:

As a test case, I disallowed the restraint of padding by replacing your `Cipher.getInstance("AES")` in decrypt method with

```
Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
```

I get a collection of unreadable characters with ***no exception***, which are understandably junk values - reason, again I used a random key which does not align to what you intend to use.

```
;l:z«1†ŠåÎàÏÙQPÞ—?ñGv’€ò;PöøïÇE1:‰§ŒÔ³
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using JSON data as string data.
you need to pick only the "response" part value of the JSON something like this

```
JSONObject jO= new JSONObject(value);
String response = jO.getString("Response");
```